# (Swift) How can I refer to an object's property from a different class?

Tags: ios, class, swift, object

I am working on making an iPhone app with Swift in Xcode. I have a switch object in one view controller, let's call it switchX, and I want an if statement in another class to refer to the state of that switch.

Here is a sample of my code

```
import UIKit
class Settings
{
    @IBOutlet var switchX: UISwitch!
    ... 
}

import UIKit
class Game
{
    @IBAction func buttonGame(sender: UIButton)
    if //here's where I need some way to determine the state of switchX
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This may be SUPER simple, I am extremely new to swift.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Settings` and `Game`? I am assuming that they are both subclasses `UIViewController`s. Will `Game` present `Settings` modally? Are they all push navigations through a `UINavigationController`? Give as much detail as possible.

Comment: First of all, don't import `UIKit` twice.

Comment: As mentioned by Ian you can use NSUserDefaults but you can also declare your var at top level and jus post a notification and add an observer to it at the class Settings viewDidload method

Answer (score 0):

You will need access to the instance of your `Settings` class.

```
var mySettings = <wherever your instance came from>
if (mySettings.switchX.on) {
  // Your switch is on.
}
```

---

As a side note, you should be updating a data model that is disjoint from your view. Run-time information should be stored in a run-time singleton data model. If you want this information to persist between app launches, you should consider using `NSUserDefaults` or a sqlite database or CoreData.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I don't think I can just initialize a new instance of my "Settings" because it extends UIViewController. I need to access it from the existing instance that is created when the user opens that view controller.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you initialize a new instance. I'm suggesting that you find a reference to the existing instance.

Comment: ^ This is how Bad practices are spread around. There SHOULD NOT be a Singleton. PASS by reference DO NOT REFERENCE Singletons! That is bad practice in a nut shell.

Comment: @JonathanNatieKlopper You've used a lot of capitalization there to push your opinion as though it's fact. Singletons are not inherently bad practice; there is a time and place for them. Global app settings are an example of something that is fundamentally well-suited to a singleton. There is a need for one and only one instance of such a class. Trying to avoid a singleton in this case is shoehorning an unsuited paradigm in its place, which is much worse practice.